# Creating automatically pages with "scraped" content for a iphone webapp

Tags: web-applications, html, scrape, hint

I'm not sure if this is the right section.

So far i've made an HTML iphone webapp  for an italian soccer news website([Pianeta Lecce](http://www.pianetalecce.it/)).

My webapp has a tabbar where you can choose the news according to a topic and i succesfully managed to do that thanks to PHP Simple Html DOM Parser([PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)) which i used to scrape the news from the website.

Now **this is the problem**:
if i click on the link whith the picture and a short summary of the news **it obviusly loads the external page of the news** .
But this is not what i want:what i want is that,when i click on the news ,it should **in some way**  create a page with the news content again scraped from the page of the site referring to that news(I just need the picture and the very piece of news!).

I think this is quite a **superable problem** but i don't really know what is **the best way to achieve this** ,especially for what concerning **simplicity**.

So i would  like you to suggest me the possible ways to do that and how you would do that.Also rember that **this is a an iPhone web application**.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in 3 steps:

1. Scrape the content from web
2. Normalize the content and add it into your DB
3. Serve the news details in a known form from your DB

This way, your app does not depend on whatever site you are scraping, since you are serving the same elements - a title, a short preview of the news and a link - elements which are stored in your DB by your scraper.

Besides that, you will also have better control over the scraping process and will be able to monitor the bad scraped news.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Anyway i don't think  this is the right solution for my problem since the news site is daily updated so i should scrape the content each time. What do you think?

Comment: indeed, the content needs to be scraped regularly. Right now, the app is scraping the content 'client-side'?

Comment: Yep,i'm scraping 'client-side'. Theoretically i can even have the acces to the main server,but, since i am not the developer of the website,i think it would be quite a mess to integrate my work to the one already done by the website developer.Thus the choise of 'client-side scraping'. Also,i'm thinking of creating a php page,news.php.This page should receieve a link sent from the main news page and then use this link to scrape the content from the website. Can this work?

Comment: If I'd have access to the server, I'd create a `web service` to be accessed by the app and return the info from there. There are problems with scraping - what will happen when the UI of the site will change for example?(not completely, only the tags you use as references to distinguish between content sections) you'll have to update **all** the installed apps in order for them to keep functioning.

Comment: web service...i don't really know what this is:can you link me anything about this? Anyway i think i'll stay with the scraping approca since they had just remade the site and they're not going to change it for now.

Comment: web service, meaning a php file that will have access straight to the DB and will send the news in a standard form to the app.